# How to dynamically add an Object from Library?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I've got in Library few MovieClips and I want to make function which is loading them into stage. My problem is I can not found different solution than making separate functions for every MovieClip. I'm looking for something like that:

```
function addAnyClip(name){
  //create new object 'name'
  stage.addChild(chosenObject);
  rest of code
}
```

because it's better than:

```
function addClip1(){
  var mc1:Clip1 = new Clip1;
  stage.addChild(mc1);
  ///rest of code
}

function addClip2(){
  var mc1:Clip2 = new Clip2;
  stage.addChild(mc2);
  ///rest of code
}

function addClip3(){
  var mc1:Clip3 = new Clip3;
  stage.addChild(mc3);
  ///rest of code
}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into using `getDefinitionByName`

You would do something like the following:

`var mcClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("NameOfClipInLibrary")`

And then just create anew object that is of the class type `mcClass`

Here are a couple of links to help explain how to use it...
http://www.jesseknowles.com/blog/dynamically_attaching_movieclips_in_as3/

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/03/31/understanding-as3-getdefinitionbyname-for-all-eval-maniacs/

Answer (score 1):

this will consolidate what you showed above:

```
function addChildOfType(type:Class):void{
    var mc:type = new type();
    stage.addChild(mc);
}
```

to use this just call:

```
addChildOfType(Clip1);
addChildOfType(Clip2);
addChildOfType(Clip3);
```

EDIT:

if your library is an externally loaded swf, then @M. Laing is correct in how to get them.  If your library is your flash library in the same flash file, then this answer will fix you up.

Comment: you are welcome!  happy coding.. oh and mark this answer as the one you wanted if you are good to go!